# Rails 3 Nested Resources and Associations (user_id nil when calling contact.note.create)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

(I could probably think of a better title for this and open to suggestions)

I am trying to call this in my NotesController, testing it in rails console:

```
    ?> u = User.first
  User Load (1.6ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT 1
=> #<User id: 2, email: nil, password: nil, linkedin_url: nil, created_at: "2012-06-17 05:54:44", updated_at: "2012-06-17 05:54:44", liid: "7fB-pQGIQi">
>> c = u.contacts.first
  Contact Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "contacts".* FROM "contacts" WHERE "contacts"."user_id" = 2 LIMIT 1
=> #<Contact id: 8, user_id: 2, created_at: "2012-06-19 01:23:45", updated_at: "2012-06-19 01:23:45">
>> c.notes.create!(:body => "this is a note")
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (23.3ms)  INSERT INTO "notes" ("body", "contact_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["body", "this is a note"], ["contact_id", 8], ["created_at", Thu, 21 Jun 2012 05:42:21 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Thu, 21 Jun 2012 05:42:21 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", nil]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
=> #<Note id: 4, created_at: "2012-06-21 05:42:21", updated_at: "2012-06-21 05:42:21", body: "this is a note", user_id: nil, contact_id: 8>
```

The problem is in the last line where it says that the Note created has a "user_id: nil". I'm wondering what I'm missing that is not allowing the note to properly get the user_id from the contact user_id? I can think of a quick fix, to set the user_id on the note object, but it seems as though it could fetch it from the contact_id, am I wrong?

Here are my models in case this is helpful:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :user_id

  belongs_to :user
  has_many :notes
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :password, :liid

  has_many :contacts
  has_many :notes, :through => :contacts
end

class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body

  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Note also needs to belong to your User:

```
class Note < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :title, :body

  belongs_to :contact
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Rails will only automatically set the foreign_key of the parent object, and not the parent object's parent like you want.  So you'll have to set that attribute manually:

```
c.notes.create!(:body => "this is a note", :user_id => c.user_id)
```

Comment: hmmm, user_id still nil. you were right though, i hadn't added belongs_to :user in Note

Comment: updated initial post to reflect new rails console session and model

Comment: Like you guessed, you'll have to set the `user_id` on the Note object manually. (updated code to reflect this)

Comment: ok, well it looks like this will be the one time where i wanted rails to be even more "magical" than it was.